# Nginx routing with multiple locations

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, next.js

I have 2 nginx location blocks set up like following:

```
root /var/www/html/;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}

location /something/ {
   alias /var/www/html/;
   try files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

The first block routes request to a next server and `/something/` routes to a react spa.
Right now, on requesting `http://example.com/something/` is still returning a 404 page which is configured in the next application.

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Due to [issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) mixing `alias` with `try_files`, you could replace the `try_files` statement with: `if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /something/index.html last; }`

Comment: But it works fine if I don't include the first block

Comment: From this tool https://nginx.viraptor.info/, looks like it suppose to work